# Status of linux service from chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

How do I check the status of a Linux service from a chef recipe?
Here is my scenario:

- I would want to perform a bunch of steps only if the service isn't running.

I would like to store the status of the service in a variable(if that is possible), so I can check the value of the variable and proceed accordingly.

Edit:

To elaborate what I am trying to accomplish.

- I have to install my application as a linux service from chef.
- But, before I install the service, I want to check if the service is already running in the machine.
- In Linux terminal, I would use the command

  > service myservice status.
- If the service is not installed the command will return

  > myservice: unrecognized service
- If it is installed and running, it will return

  > run.sh (pid 10777) is running...

I would like to determine the status of myservice before I proceed with the installation in the chef recipe.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Mind rewriting this or going into more detail?  I think an example would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a simple helper like this:

```rb
module MyServiceChecker
  def my_service_running?
    cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('/etc/init.d/my_service status')
    cmd.run_command
    cmd.exitstatus == 0
  end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, MyServiceChecker)
Chef::Resource.send(:include, MyServiceChecker)
Chef::Provider.send(:include, MyServiceChecker)
```

And then use this helper when you want to check if the service is running. Depending on your service and Linux derivative, the command may be different.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to use cmd.exitstatus to get the command status.